# Explosive Force of exploding manhole required to lift van in air?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces

I need to work out the explosive Force required to lift a van from the ground.

Using F = MA

For e.g. If a standard van is approx. 5700 lbs (2600 kg) and we can assume that a manhole explodes directly upwards – what calculation can you make using this weight?

If F = MA and the Mass is 2600kg and we assume Acceleration is 5m/s^2 then I get a Force of 13000 N. Would this be 13kN? (Or should it be in Joules?)

Does this all seem correct?

Comment: This question is unclear to me.  Do you just want it to lift a specific height, a specific starting acceleration?  It's not clear what exactly you are trying to calculate.

Answer (score 1):

The net force on the body will be equal to mass times acceleration. There is force even due to gravity which you didn't consider. So the final expression which you will get will be: $\rm F - mg = ma$ ($g$ being gravity).